# Substract from grandTotal when remove a dynamically row

Tags: javascript, dynamic, row

Up till now this script can:

- Add dynamically rows and remove them.
- Multiply, sum the subtotals and get the granTotal.

But I´m not able to substract from grandTotal when a row is removed. Can you please show how can I get it? Thanks.

```
$(document).on("change", "input", function () {
    $(".price").keyup(function() {
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $("input[name='qty[]']").each(function (index) {
            var qty = $("input[name='qty[]']").eq(index).val();
            var price = $("input[name='price[]']").eq(index).val();
            var output = parseInt(qty) * parseInt(price);
            if (!isNaN(output)) {
                $("input[name='output[]']").eq(index).val(output);
                grandTotal = parseInt(grandTotal) + parseInt(output);
                $('#gran').val(grandTotal);
            }
        });
    });
});    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.voca:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);
        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.btn-add:not(:last)')
            .removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-danger')
            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
            .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove   ');
    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
    {
        $(this).parents('.voca:first').remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="control-group" >
    <div class="controls">
        <form role="form" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="row">                   
                <div class="voca">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input class="form-control qty" name="qty[]" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input class="form-control price" name="price[]" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input class="form-control output" placeholder="" name="output[]" type="text" value="" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add" >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </form>
        <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="grand">
    Grand Total:<input type="text" name="gran" id="gran" readonly>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option on button click

```
 var remVal = $(this).prev().find('input').val();
  var grandVal = $('#gran').val();
  $(this).parents('.voca:first').remove();
  $('#gran').val(grandVal - remVal);
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("change", "input", function() {
  $(".price").keyup(function() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    var x = [];
    $("input[name='qty[]']").each(function(index) {
      var qty = $("input[name='qty[]']").eq(index).val();
      var price = $("input[name='price[]']").eq(index).val();
      var output = parseInt(qty) * parseInt(price);
      if (!isNaN(output)) {
        $("input[name='output[]']").eq(index).val(output);
        grandTotal = parseInt(grandTotal) + parseInt(output);
        $('#gran').val(grandTotal);
        x[0] = grandTotal;
      }
    });
  });
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
    currentEntry = $(this).parents('.voca:first'),
    newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);
  newEntry.find('input').val('');
  controlForm.find('.btn-add:not(:last)')
    .removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-danger')
    .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
    .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove   ');
}).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {

  var remVal = $(this).prev().find('input').val();
  var grandVal = $('#gran').val();

  console.log($(this).prev().find('input').val());
  $(this).parents('.voca:first').remove();
  $('#gran').val(grandVal - remVal);
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Codepen -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xOajYb

Comment: Thanks @rafpre , please vote my post , if it helped your question :)